# Force height of DIV to 100%

Tags: html, height, css

I downloaded a website template to use for a small project but for some reason the sidebar used for navigation gets cut short when the content DIV isn't at least the height of the page. I've been tinkering with the CSS and inspecting it through Firefox Web Developer but aside from having the "min-height" set to something very large, I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Any suggestions as to what to look at in the CSS would be greatly appreciated.

http://brutalservers.com/dp/index.html

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Device Portal</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/hideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.equalHeight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
          $(".tablesorter").tablesorter(); 
     } 
    );
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.column').equalHeight();
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <header id="header">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site_title"><a href="index.html">Device Portal</a></h1>
            <h2 class="section_title">Dashboard</h2><div class="btn_view_site"><a href="http://www.medialoot.com">View Site</a></div>
        </hgroup>
    </header> <!-- end of header bar -->

    <section id="secondary_bar">
        <div class="user">
            <p>Brett Powell (<a href="#">3 Messages</a>)</p>
            <!-- <a class="logout_user" href="#" title="Logout">Logout</a> -->
        </div>
        <div class="breadcrumbs_container">
            <article class="breadcrumbs"><a href="index.html">Website Admin</a> <div class="breadcrumb_divider"></div> <a class="current">Dashboard</a></article>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end of secondary bar -->

    <aside id="sidebar" class="column">
        <form class="quick_search">
            <input type="text" value="Quick Search" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;">
        </form>
        <hr/>
        <h3>Devices</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_new_article"><a href="#">New Article</a></li>
            <li class="icn_edit_article"><a href="#">Edit Articles</a></li>
            <li class="icn_categories"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
            <li class="icn_tags"><a href="#">Tags</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Datacenters</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_add_user"><a href="#">Add New User</a></li>
            <li class="icn_view_users"><a href="#">View Users</a></li>
            <li class="icn_profile"><a href="#">Your Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>IP Allocations</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_folder"><a href="#">File Manager</a></li>
            <li class="icn_photo"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li class="icn_audio"><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
            <li class="icn_video"><a href="#">Video</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Inventory</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_settings"><a href="#">Options</a></li>
            <li class="icn_security"><a href="#">Security</a></li>
            <li class="icn_jump_back"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

    </aside><!-- end of sidebar -->

    <section id="main" class="column">

        <article class="module width_3_quarter">
        <header><h3 class="tabs_involved">Content Manager</h3>
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab1">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Comments</a></li>
        </ul>
        </header>

        <div class="tab_container">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th></th> 
                    <th>Entry Name</th> 
                    <th>Category</th> 
                    <th>Created On</th> 
                    <th>Actions</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td> 
                    <td>Articles</td> 
                    <td>5th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Ipsum Lorem Dolor Sit Amet</td> 
                    <td>Freebies</td> 
                    <td>6th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Sit Amet Dolor Ipsum</td> 
                    <td>Tutorials</td> 
                    <td>10th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Dolor Lorem Amet</td> 
                    <td>Articles</td> 
                    <td>16th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Dolor Lorem Amet</td> 
                    <td>Articles</td> 
                    <td>16th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr>  
            </tbody> 
            </table>
            </div><!-- end of #tab1 -->

            <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th></th> 
                    <th>Comment</th> 
                    <th>Posted by</th> 
                    <th>Posted On</th> 
                    <th>Actions</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td> 
                    <td>Mark Corrigan</td> 
                    <td>5th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Ipsum Lorem Dolor Sit Amet</td> 
                    <td>Jeremy Usbourne</td> 
                    <td>6th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Sit Amet Dolor Ipsum</td> 
                    <td>Super Hans</td> 
                    <td>10th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Dolor Lorem Amet</td> 
                    <td>Alan Johnson</td> 
                    <td>16th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
                    <td>Dolor Lorem Amet</td> 
                    <td>Dobby</td> 
                    <td>16th April 2011</td> 
                    <td><input type="image" src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"><input type="image" src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
            </table>

            </div><!-- end of #tab2 -->

        </div><!-- end of .tab_container -->

        </article><!-- end of content manager article -->

        <article class="module width_quarter">
            <header><h3>Messages</h3></header>
            <div class="message_list">
                <div class="module_content">
                    <div class="message"><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor.</p>
                    <p><strong>John Doe</strong></p></div>
                    <div class="message"><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor.</p>
                    <p><strong>John Doe</strong></p></div>
                    <div class="message"><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor.</p>
                    <p><strong>John Doe</strong></p></div>
                    <div class="message"><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor.</p>
                    <p><strong>John Doe</strong></p></div>
                    <div class="message"><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor.</p>
                    <p><strong>John Doe</strong></p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <form class="post_message">
                    <input type="text" value="Message" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn_post_message" value=""/>
                </form>
            </footer>
        </article><!-- end of messages article -->

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </section>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Essentials */

html, div, map, dt, isindex, form, header, aside, section, section, article, footer {  
    display: block;  
} 

html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
background: #F8F8F8;
font-size: 12px;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}

.spacer {
height: 20px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
color: #77BACE;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Header */

header#header {
height: 55px;
width: 100%;
background: #222222 url(../images/header_bg.png) repeat-x;
}

header#header h1.site_title, header#header h2.section_title {
float: left;
margin: 0;
font-size: 22px;
display: block;
width: 23%;
height: 55px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: left;
text-indent: 1.8%;
line-height: 55px;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

header#header h1.site_title a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

header#header h2.section_title {
text-align: center;
text-indent: 4.5%;
width: 68%;
background: url(../images/header_shadow.png) no-repeat left top;
}

.btn_view_site {
float: left;
width: 9%;
}

.btn_view_site a {
display: block;
margin-top: 12px;
width: 91px;
height: 27px;
background: url(../images/btn_view_site.png) no-repeat;
text-align: center;
line-height: 29px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;}

.btn_view_site a:hover {
background-position: 0 -27px;
}

/* Secondary Header Bar */

section#secondary_bar {
height: 38px;
width: 100%;
background: #F1F1F4 url(../images/secondary_bar.png) repeat-x;
}

section#secondary_bar .user {
float: left;
width: 23%;
height: 38px;
}

.user p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #666666;
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 85%;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
text-indent: 25px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
background: url(../images/icn_user.png) no-repeat center left;
margin-left: 6%;
}

.user a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #666666}

.user a:hover {
color: #77BACE;
}

.user a.logout_user {
float: left;
display: block;
width: 16px;
height: 35px;
text-indent: -5000px;
background: url(../images/icn_logout.png) center no-repeat;
}

/* Breadcrumbs */

section#secondary_bar .breadcrumbs_container {
float: left;
width: 77%;
background: url(../images/secondary_bar_shadow.png) no-repeat left top;
height: 38px;
}

article.breadcrumbs {
float: left;
padding: 0 10px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
height: 23px;
margin: 4px 3%;
}

.breadcrumbs a {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 24px;
line-height: 23px;
}

.breadcrumbs a.current, .breadcrumbs a.current:hover {
color: #9E9E9E;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumbs a:link, .breadcrumbs a:visited {
color: #44474F;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-weight: bold;}

.breadcrumbs a:hover {
color: #222222;
}

.breadcrumb_divider {
display: inline-block;
width: 12px;
height: 24px;
background: url(../images/breadcrumb_divider.png) no-repeat;
float: left;
margin: 0 5px;
}

/* Sidebar */

aside#sidebar {
width: 23%;
background: #E0E0E3 url(../images/sidebar.png) repeat;
float: left;
min-height: 500px;
margin-top: -4px;
}

#sidebar hr {
border: none;
outline: none;
background: url(../images/sidebar_divider.png) repeat-x;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;}


/* Search */

.quick_search {
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 0 10px 0;
}

.quick_search input[type=text] {
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
height: 26px;
width: 90%;
color: #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
text-indent: 30px;
background: #fff url(../images/icn_search.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 10px 6px;
}

.quick_search input[type=text]:focus {
outline: none;
color: #666666;
border: 1px solid #77BACE;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
}

/* Sidebar Menu */

#sidebar h3 {
color: #1F1F20;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 13px;
margin: 10px 0 10px 6%;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 90%;
}

.toggleLink {
color: #999999;
font-size: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
float: right;
margin-right: 2%
}

#sidebar .toggleLink:hover {
color: #77BACE;
text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar ul {
clear: both;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 0 12%; padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li a {
color: #666666;
padding-left: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
height: 17px;
line-height: 17px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
margin: 2px 0;
}

#sidebar li a:hover {
color: #444444;
}

/* Sidebar Icons */

#sidebar li.icn_new_article a {
background: url(../images/icn_new_article.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_edit_article a {
background: url(../images/icn_edit_article.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_categories a {
background: url(../images/icn_categories.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_tags a {
background: url(../images/icn_tags.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_add_user a {
background: url(../images/icn_add_user.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_view_users a {
background: url(../images/icn_view_users.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_profile a {
background: url(../images/icn_profile.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_folder a {
background: url(../images/icn_folder.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_photo a {
background: url(../images/icn_photo.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_audio a {
background: url(../images/icn_audio.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_video a {
background: url(../images/icn_video.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_settings a {
background: url(../images/icn_settings.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_security a {
background: url(../images/icn_security.png) no-repeat center left;
}
#sidebar li.icn_jump_back a {
background: url(../images/icn_jump_back.png) no-repeat center left;
}

#sidebar p {
color: #666666;
padding-left: 6%;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;}

#sidebar a {
color: #666666;
text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

#sidebar footer {
margin-top: 20%;
}


/* Main Content */


section#main {
width: 77%;
min-height: 500px;
background: url(../images/sidebar_shadow.png) repeat-y left top;
float: left;
margin-top: -2px;
}

#main h3 {
color: #1F1F20;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 13px;
margin: 8px 20px;
}

/* Modules */

.module {
border: 1px solid #9BA0AF;
width: 100%;
margin: 20px 3% 0 3%;
margin-top: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #ffffff;
}

#main .module header h3 {
display: block;
width: 90%;
float: left;
}

.module header {
height: 38px;
width: 100%;
background: #F1F1F4 url(../images/secondary_bar.png) repeat-x;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.module footer {
height: 32px;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #9CA1B0;
background: #F1F1F4 url(../images/module_footer_bg.png) repeat-x;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.module_content {
margin: 10px 20px;
color: #666;}

/* Module Widths */

.width_full {
width: 95%;
}

.width_half {
width: 46%;
margin-right: 0;
float: left;
}

.width_quarter {
width: 26%;
margin-right: 0;
float: left;
}

.width_3_quarter {
width: 66%;
margin-right: 0;
float: left;
}

/* Stats Module */

.stats_graph {
width: 64%;
float: left;
}

.stats_overview {
background: #F6F6F6;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
float: right;
width: 26%;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.overview_today, .overview_previous {
width: 50%;
float: left;}

.stats_overview p {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.stats_overview p.overview_day {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 6px 0;
}

.stats_overview p.overview_count {
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #333333;}

.stats_overview p.overview_type {
font-size: 10px;
color: #999999;
margin-bottom: 8px}

/* Content Manager */

.tablesorter {
width: 100%;
margin: -5px 0 0 0;
}

.tablesorter td{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.tablesorter thead tr {
height: 34px;
background: url(../images/table_sorter_header.png) repeat-x;
text-align: left;
text-indent: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.tablesorter td {
padding: 15px 10px;
}

.tablesorter input[type=image] {
margin-right: 10px;}

ul.tabs {
    margin: 3px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    height: 24px; /*--Set height of tabs--*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 24px;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    color: #44474F;
}

html ul.tabs li.active a  {
    color: #44474F;
    }

html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #F1F2F4;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px #818181;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px #818181;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px #818181;
}

html ul.tabs li:first-child, html ul.tabs li:first-child a  {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

html ul.tabs li:last-child, html ul.tabs li:last-child a  {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#main .module header h3.tabs_involved {
display: block;
width: 60%;
float: left;
}

/* Messages */

.message {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;
}

input[type=submit] {
background: #D0D1D4 url(../images/btn_submit.png) repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #A8A9A8;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-weight: bold;
height: 22px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 0 10px;
color: #666;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
color: #333333;
}

input[type=submit].alt_btn {
background: #D0D1D4 url(../images/btn_submit_2.png) repeat-x;
border: 1px solid#30B0C8;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-weight: bold;
height: 22px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 0 10px;
color: #003E49;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #6CDCF9;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit].alt_btn:hover {
color: #001217;
}

input[type=submit].btn_post_message {
background: #D0D1D4 url(../images/post_message.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
width: 37px;
border: none;
height: 24px;
cursor: pointer;
text-indent: -5000px;
}

input[type=submit].btn_post_message:hover {
background-position: 0 -24px;
}

.post_message {
text-align: left;
padding: 5px 0;
}

.post_message input[type=text] {
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
height: 20px;
width: 70%;
color: #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
text-indent: 10px;
background-position: 10px 6px;
float: left;
margin: 0 3.5%;
}

.post_message input[type=text]:focus {
outline: none;
border: 1px solid #77BACE;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
color: #666666;
}

.post_message input[type=image] {
float: left;
}

.message_list {
height: 250px;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* New/Edit Article Module */

fieldset {
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #F6F6F6;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 1% 0%;
margin: 10px 0;
}

fieldset label {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-weight: bold;
padding-left: 10px;
/*margin: -5px 0 5px 0;*/
text-transform: uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset input[type=text] {
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
height: 20px;
color: #666666;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
padding-left: 10px;
background-position: 10px 6px;
margin: 0;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 96%;
margin: 0 10px;
}

fieldset input[type=text]:focus {
outline: none;
border: 1px solid #77BACE;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
}

fieldset select {
width: 96%;
margin: 0 10px;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
height: 20px;
color: #666666;
}

fieldset textarea {
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
color: #666666;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 1px 0 #fff;
padding-left: 10px;
background-position: 10px 6px;
margin: 0 0.5%;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 96%;
margin: 0 10px;
}

fieldset textarea:focus {
outline: none;
border: 1px solid #77BACE;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #ccc, 0 0 10px #ADDCE6;
}

.submit_link {
float: right;
margin-right: 3%;
padding: 5px 0;
}

.submit_link select {
width: 150px;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
height: 20px;
color: #666666;
}

#main .module_content h1 {
color: #333333;
text-transform: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 22px;
margin: 8px 0px;
}

#main .module_content h2 {
color: #444444;
text-transform: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 18px;
margin: 8px 0px;
}

#main .module_content h3 {
color: #666666;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 13px;
margin: 8px 0px;
}

#main .module_content h4 {
color: #666666;
text-transform: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 13px;
margin: 8px 0px;
}

#main .module_content li {
line-height: 150%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the css and html from the template?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I added both now. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height of these two elements two 100%

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="column" style="height: 100%;">
<section id="main" class="column" style="height: 100%;">
```

the style is also inline

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of your sidebar 100% and it will work

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="column" style="height: 100%;">
```